# Why does .sort() behave incorrectly when alphabetically sorting some arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

There's a weird JavaScript behavior I came across.
If I try to sort
`['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h','i', 'j']` with `[].sort((a, b) => a > b)`, it returns the array sorted correctly (in this case, exactly as it was before), but if I add one more item to the array, like:

```
['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h','i', 'j', 'k'].sort(
  (a, b) => a > b
)
```

it returns:

`["f", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"]`

Oddly enough, if I add "l" to the array, it returns:

`["g", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]`
('f' now is in the correct place, but 'g' is not o.O)

If I use the `.sort` method without providing a comparator it sorts correctly, but that's of no use to me, since I'm actually trying to sort an array of objects by a property, like:

`[{ firstName: 'Peter' }, { firstName: 'Alfred' }]`

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure that is Javascript?

Comment: @Waruyama, this is the latest version of JavaScript: ES6 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `.sort()` comparator function is incorrect. The `.sort()` comparator should return a negative number when the first value should sort before the second; a positive number when the second should sort before the first; and 0 when they should be considered the same value for ordering purposes.

Your comparator returns `true` or `false`, which will be interpreted as 1 or 0.  Thus when `a` is less than `b`, your comparator tells `.sort()` that it's *the same* as `b`.

Strings have a handy method available that works great for sorting:

```
['world', 'hello'].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
```

When sorting numbers, you can just return the result of a subtraction operation.

Comment: Subtraction cannot work. If `a = maxint` and `b = -3`, then `a - b` will return a negative number, incorrectly indicating that `a < b`.

Comment: @JimMischel yes, that is true. It is often the case that numbers are naturally constrained in a particular application, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function should return a negative number if a < b, 0 if a = b, and a positive number if a > b, so it should look like this:

```
(a, b) => {
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `sort()` function will use the `compareFunction` to specify the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, according to the string conversion of each element.

Try using something like:

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort for more information

Comment: I downvoted because your comparison function is broken. If a and b are integers, with a being very large (say, `maxint`) and b is, say, -20, that "comparison" function will return the wrong result.

Comment: @JimMischel I pulled that function off of the Mozilla website that I linked to in my answer.  I figure if it's good enough for Mozilla, it should be good enough for SO (Silly me, what was I thinking?).  While you are technically correct, your assertion in the context of this question is invalid since OP is using strings.  Now, I know that my function name (`compareNumbers`) is also incorrect in the context of this question, but both issues are easily fixable.  If I fix them, will you remove your downvote?

Comment: Incorrect is incorrect, regardless of where it came from. This wouldn't be the first time incorrect code was found in a documentation example. If the OP is comparing strings, then subtraction is meaningless. If the comparison is characters, then subtraction is still wrong unless you can guarantee that arithmetic overflow will never be an issue. I'm not convinced you can make that guarantee in Javascript. You certainly can't make that guarantee in Java, C#, C++, etc.